# React Enzyme component find deeper in the tree

Tags: react-redux

when we use component.find() in a nested component can we search all the levels without specifying each component along the path...

e.g. currently do something like this:

```
component
  .find(AutoSizer)
  .find(Grid)
  .find(???)
  .find(thingWeWant)
```

How can I select for a component which is at any level of the tree(recursively search all nested child components) or how can I see the structure of the tree so I can fill in every level with the correct component?

```
const renderComponent = (props) => {
    <Provider store={ createStore(reducer, initialState) }>
       <ChildComponentTypeA { ...props }/>
           <ChildComponentTypeB { ...props }/>
              <more child components since component of type B is from a library>
           </ChildComponentTypeB>
       </ChildComponentTypeA>
    </Provider>
```

};